# Razor Page returning only one row item from stored procedure - How to return all rows of procedure result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, razor-pages

I have finally figured out how to generate a razor page with data from my stored procedure. But only the first or last row item is being returned.

I have tried using `nextresult()`, but this has not worked. I believe this only applies if I expect data from more than one table. My stored procedure has some joins to other tables, but there is only one result set. I just need all of my values from that result set to be printed.

When I execute my stored procedure in SSRS or in SSMS, I get multiple values returned. Here is my SQL code.

```
SELECT Movies.MovieTitle, Movies.MovieYear, Genres.GenreName 
FROM Movies 
INNER JOIN GenresMovies AS gm ON gm.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
INNER JOIN Genres ON Genres.GenreID = gm.GenreID
WHERE Genres.GenreID IN (SELECT Number FROM [fn_SplitInt](@GenreID, ','))
```

Here is my access layer, newly updated from feedback.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyMovies.Models
{
    public class MovieDataAccessLayer
    {
        public List<Movies> GetMovieByMedia(byte? MediaID)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=ServerName;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            var movies = new Movies();

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MovieByMedia", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MediaID", SqlDbType.TinyInt) { Value = MediaID });
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    con.Open();

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        List<Movies> Movies = new List<Movies>();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Movies movie = new Movies()
                            {
                                MovieTitle = reader["MovieTitle"].ToString(),
                                MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieYear"])
                            };
                            Movies.Add(movie);
                        }
                    }

                    return Movies;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the cshtml.cs where I execute the stored procedure, newly updated.

```
namespace MyMovies.Pages.MovieDetails
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyMovies.Models.MyMoviesContext _context;

        public DetailsModel(MyMovies.Models.MyMoviesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        MovieDataAccessLayer objmovie = new MovieDataAccessLayer();
        public List <Movies> { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(byte? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Movies = objmovie.GetMovieByMedia(id);

            if (Movies == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, the razor page to display a table with the results, newly updated!!

```
@page
@model MyMovies.Pages.MovieDetails.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Movie Title</th>
        <th>Movie Year</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieTitle)
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieYear)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

It either returns the first or the last row item. What can I do to get it to return all? If I try doing a foreach loop, I would have to make my movies class `IEnumerable`. But doing it that way, I couldn't figure out how to get my stored procedure to work.

Comment: You return only one, cuz you use one model but you need use List<Movies>

Comment: And in razor page you need use foreach by list models

Comment: @evilGenius, so do I have to change my movies to type enumerable? Could you provide me some more detail, I'm really struggling to piece this together as I'm not familiar with c#.

Comment: When I tried before using List<Movies> I ran into many issues, the main being that I couldn't convert type movies into list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Movies> Movies = new List<Movies>();

while (reader.Read())
{
        Movies movie = new Movies()
        {
          MovieTitle = reader["MovieTitle"].ToString(),
          MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieYear"])
        }

        Movies.Add(movie);
};

return Movies;
```

Check this:

```
public List<Movies> GetMovieByMedia(byte? MediaID)
{
    string connectionString = "Server=ServerName;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

    var movies = new Movies();

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MovieByMedia", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MediaID", SqlDbType.TinyInt) { Value = MediaID });
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Movies> Movies = new List<Movies>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                     Movies movie = new Movies()
                                    {
                                         MovieTitle = reader["MovieTitle"].ToString(),
                                         MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieYear"])
                                    };
                     Movies.Add(movie);
                }
            }

            return Movies;
}
```

New code

```
public List<Movies> Movies { get; set; }
Movies = objmovie.GetMovieByMedia(id);
```

Markup for razor page:

```
@using Movies
<table>
@foreach(var item in model.Movies)
{
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.MovieTitle)
        </th>
        <th class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => item.MovieYear)
        </th>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I hope it works. I can't check this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192505/discussion-on-answer-by-evilgenius-razor-page-returning-only-one-row-item-from-s).